# Python openCV error while using cv2.imread()

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#load color of an image in grayscale
img1 = cv2.imread('Tarun.jpg',0)

cv2.imshow('Hey its me Tarun yellogi',img1)
```

---

```
error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Comment: next to the .py is the image?

Comment: Your img1 is empty.  Add the path to the Tarun.jpg, if it is not in your working directory.

Answer (score 3):

> `img1 = cv2.imread('Tarun.jpg',0)`

As you know, `imread` reads in the specified image. With just the filename, as here, python tries to read the image from the current working directory. If the file does not exist, no error is reported and `img1` will have a value of `None`.

That this line:

> `cv2.imshow('Hey its me Tarun yellogi',img1)`

returns an error of:

> `error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow`

means that the image specified in the `imshow` command (i.e. `img1`) has a width and/or a height of 0. What the error message is saying is that the image in function `imshow` must have a size where the width is greater than zero ***and*** the height is greater than zero.

You can check the image size with `img1.shape`. In this case you will probably get an error message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`. You can further check if `img1` is `None` with `img1 == None`. If you get a response of `True` then you will know that `img1` does not contain image data.

**TL;DR**

The file 'Tarun.jpg' was not found thus `img1 == None`.

Comment: Unexplained downvotes... I get tired of having points in my answers incorporated into other answers with a coincident downvote...

Answer (score 1):

- These kind of error occur when the path to the image is wrong
- Or the image does not exist
- Or the image is corrupted
- If the image is not in the current directory then you have to mention the absolute path to the image
- Use `os` module to make the path work in any other machine instead of hard-coding the absolute path
- But this error message means that `imshow()` is not getting the right image to display
- I would check the shape and the values of the image to make sure that the image is not corrupt or image is not `None`: `print(img1.shape)` and `print(img1)`
- If the image with the path does not exist then `cv2.imread()` returns `None`
- The error also indicates that the width and heights of the image is zero which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this in reading the pictures in a loop to prevent the pause by Nonetype error! It helps me in my case(Some jpg files is Nonetype in my case)

```
if img is None:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is not in the current directory then you have to mention the absolute path to the image.

Use `os` module to make the path work in any other machine instead of hard-coding the absolute path.

But this error message means that `imshow()` is not getting the right image to display.
I would check the shape and the values of the image to make sure that the image is not corrupt.