# Python - cv2 package is not showing any function while typing in pycharm

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("Resources/0017.png")
cv2.imshow('Window',img)
```

but when I am typing cv2. it doesn't show/suggest that I can use "imshow" function.

Error I'm getting is:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-6lylwdcz\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: I created a folder "imgs" under the virtual environment root (venv) and put the image inside the "imgs" folder and accessed it as:

img = cv2.imread("imgs/0017.png")

It worked. Thanks for the time and help guys.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion failed meaning that the file path does not exist or the file is corrupted. Please check the path for your image and make sure it is spelled correctly, and that the image is in the same folder as the python program (the working directory), or include the whole path.

**Additional Links / Sources** 
[Python openCV error while using cv2.imread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938738/python-opencv-error-while-using-cv2-imread) 
[I couldn't get past this error in open cv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674116/i-couldnt-get-past-this-error-in-open-cv?noredirect=1&lq=1)